# Spyder shortcuts changing doesn't work

Tags: python, spyder

I tried to change two shortcuts:

```
       editor.......toggle comment.......Ctrl(Mod3)+Blackslash
       editor.......code completion......Shift(Mod3)+Space

but after restart spyder,press,

       Ctrl+Backslash             Nothing happended
       Ctrl+Space                 Space got input


 What is the problem here?
```

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) Spyder 3.0 beta2 already has a simpler and more intuitive way to introduce shortcuts. It'll be released in a couple of months.